# How to link package lib in react native ios?

Tags: react-native

I tried to link packages using **react native link** command as well as **manually** and what does mean by **Recovered References**. my unlinked libs are showing there and how to resolve it?.

2.) Unable to link **libRNvectoricons.a** under Build Phrases > **Link Binary With Libraries**. could not find option there to link up.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Recovered References.]

[image: Build Phrases > Link Binary With Libraries]

Comment: Have you ejected your react-native app?

Comment: Nup..i have not..i m new in IOS development..

Comment: What libraries required to be linked? please add them to your question

Comment: I want to add react-native-app-auth package in my project. i have followed all the steps but not getting success.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. Delete the `node_modules` folder inside the project
2. run `npm uninstall react-native-app-auth`
3. run `npm install react-native-app-auth --save`
4. run `react-native link react-native-app-auth`
5. Then follow [these steps](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth#setup) (iOS Setup & Android Setup)

Comment: Your welcome! If it solved your question please accept the answer.